# Limit of an infinite sum can be computed from limit of each component?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Let $\{a_{n,k}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose that 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n,k}=0 \text{ }  \text{ } \forall k=1,...,2n
$$
Does this imply
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{2n} a_{n,k}=0
$$
? Could you help me to understand why yes or no?

Comment: But you still use $n$ in two different roles in your first formula. In the limit and outside of it. Still not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $a_{n, k} = 1/n$. Then, for any fixed $k$, we have $a_{n, k} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. But,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{2n}a_{n, k} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{n} = \frac{2n}{n} = 2$$
and hence
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{2n} a_{n, k} = 2$$