# Convergence of the sum of two infinite double-index summation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, measure-theory

My question is about the convergence of sums of two-dimensional arrays of reals. What I mean by a two-dimensional array is a mapping on $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. Let $b_{n,k}$ be such a mapping, i.e. $(n,k) \mapsto b_{n,k}$.

Let
$$
a_n\equiv \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \log(G(b_{n,k}))
$$
and
$$
\tilde{a}_n \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{2n}  (1-G(b_{n,k}))
$$
**Assume also that**

- $G:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ ,
- $G$ continuous and strictly monotone increasing on $\mathbb{R}$.
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}G(x)=1$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}G(x)=0$
- $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_{n,k}=\infty$ $\forall k$ (which implies $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}G(b_{n,k})=1$ $\forall k$)

I want to show
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n+\tilde{a}_n)=0
$$
and your hint would be extremely appreciated

---

This is what I have tried to do and where I am stuck:

Step 1: 
$$
\begin{cases}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \log(G(b_{n,k}))=0 & \forall k\in 1,...,2n\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1-G(b_{n,k}))=0 & \forall k\in 1,...,2n\\
\end{cases}
$$

Step 2 (**wrong** as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750083/limit-of-an-infinite-sum-can-be-computed-from-limit-of-each-component)):
from Step 1 it follows
$$
\begin{cases}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \log(G(b_{n,k}))=0  \\
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{2n}  (1-G(b_{n,k}))=0 \\
\end{cases}
$$
which implies
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Big[\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\log(G(b_{n,k}))+\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (1-G(b_{n,k}))\Big]=0
$$

Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23057/under-what-condition-we-can-interchange-order-of-a-limit-and-a-summation) question on the possibility of exchanging limit and infinite summation  may be related.

Comment: If $G$ is actually $\to (0,1)$, we can take $c_n$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=\infty$ and $G(c_n)<1-1/\sqrt{n}$ (say). And then your statement fails (with $b_{n,k}=c_n$ independent on $k$). You're really trying to prove something more specific.

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks for your help. Is your example compatible with the assumptions I have added? Why?

Comment: Also: the hint that I received from the professor is: for $G\rightarrow 1$ we have that $-\log(G)\approx 1-G$

Comment: I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $c_n=\sup\{c\in\mathbb{R}\ :\ G(c) \leqslant 1-1/\sqrt{n}\}$. Then $c_n$ is monotonically nondecreasing (clearly); $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n = \infty$ (otherwise, if this limit is $c\in\mathbb{R}$, by continuity we would have $G(c)=1$); finally, $G(c_n) \leqslant 1-1/\sqrt{n}$ (again by continuity).

Now take $b_{n,k}=c_n$ independent on $k$. As $1-x+\log{x}<-(1-x)^2/2$ for $x\in(0,1)$, we get $a_n+\tilde{a}_n<-1$ for all $n$. The statement fails.

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify how you go from $1-x+\log(x)<...$ to $a_n+\tilde{a}_n<-1$?

Comment: $a_n+\tilde{a}_n$ is the sum of $2n$ identical terms equal to $1-x+\log{x}$ with $x=1-1/\sqrt{n}$, which is $<-1/(2n)$.

Comment: why with $x=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$? Should it be with $x\leq 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$?

Comment: Ok, sorry, take $\leqslant$ instead of $=$ ;) The inequality still holds.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. For $n$ large we have that $\log(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})=-[ 1-(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})]$ (which is the hint of my professor). How is that related to your answer? Also, does something change if our objective is to claim $a_n=-\tilde{a}_n+o(1)$ where $o(1)$ is a quantity going to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Your professor is right in the sense that $-\log(1-x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k}$ for $x\in(0,1)$. So $-x-\log(1-x)$ is _at least_ $\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{2}$. This is "not small enough". We took $x_n=n^{-1/2}$ and got $|a_n+\tilde{a}_n|>1$. I could take $x_n=n^{-\epsilon}$ and get $|a_n+\tilde{a}_n|>n^{1-2\epsilon}$. This is not only not $o(1)$ - this may grow unbounded.

Comment: Ok, if I take $x_n\equiv n^{-1}$, then it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76463/discussion-between-metamorphy-and-cgt).

Comment: Please give a look to my related question, it is very similar but I am imposing a specific structure to $b_{n,k}$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750587/convergence-of-the-sum-of-two-infinite-sums

Comment: @CGT I should have defined $c_n$ this way for $n>1$ (as we analyse $n\to\infty$, this really doesn't matter). In this setting, the set in question (omit the $\sup$) is nonempty due to conditions on $G$ (I don't impose anything in addition to what you did - and I don't understand what do you mean saying that a function is growing slower than a sequence...). As of the related question - a bit later... I'm kinda short of time :(