# Convergence of the sum of two infinite sums

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

[This question is a refinement of my other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750122/convergence-of-the-sum-of-two-infinite-double-index-summation) for a specific $b_{n,k}$]

Consider

- a  mapping $u$ on $\mathbb{N} \mapsto (0,\infty)$ with $k \mapsto u(k)\equiv u_k$, bounded in absolute value  by  $\bar{u}<\infty$.
- a  mapping $a$ on $\mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with $n\mapsto a(n)\equiv a_n$.
- a  mapping $b$ on $\mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with $n\mapsto b(n)\equiv b_n$.

$\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, let
$$
c_n(t)\equiv \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \log(G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n))
$$
and
$$
\tilde{c}_n(t) \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{2n}  (1-G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n))
$$
**Assume also that**

- $G:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$
- $G$ continuous and strictly monotone increasing on $\mathbb{R}$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}G(x)=1$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}G(x)=0$
- **ADDED**: $G$ is such that 
  $$
  \exists \text{ }A:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,\infty) \text{ s.t. } \lim_{s\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1-G(s+v A(s))}{1-G(s)} = e^{-v}\text{ }\forall v \in \mathbb{R}
  $$
  Moreover, $A(s)\equiv \frac{1-G(s)}{g(s)}$ where $G(s)\equiv \int_{-\infty}^s g(e) de$ $\forall s \in \mathbb{R}$.
- $b_n\equiv G^{-1}(1-\frac{1}{n})$, so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_{n}=\infty$ (which implies $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}G(b_{n})=1$)
- $a_n\equiv A(b_n)$.
- Under these conditions it can be shown that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n)=1$ $\forall k$ $\forall t$.

I want to show that $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(c_n(t)+\tilde{c}_n(t))=0
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
c_n(t)=-\tilde{c}_n(t)+o(1)
$$
and your help would be extremely appreciated

---

**I have attempted to start the proof (incomplete!)**

**CASE 1**: $t$ such that $t+\bar{u}\leq 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $t+u_k\leq 0$. 
In this case 
$$
0<G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n)\leq G(a_n*(t+\bar{u})+b_n)\leq G(b_n)=1-\frac{1}{n} \hspace{1cm} \text{$\forall n, k$}
$$
$$
\Downarrow
$$
$$
0<G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n)\leq 1-\frac{1}{n} \hspace{1cm} \text{$\forall n, k$}
$$
We know that for $x\in (0,1)$ $1-x+\log(x)\leq -(1-x)^2/2$. Applying this rule to $1-\frac{1}{n}$, we get
$$
1-(1-\frac{1}{n})+\log(1-\frac{1}{n})\leq -\frac{1}{2n^2} \hspace{1cm} \text{$\forall n$}
$$
We can show that if $0<G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n)\leq 1-\frac{1}{n}$, then $$1-G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n)+\log(G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n))\leq 1-(1-\frac{1}{n})+\log(1-\frac{1}{n}) \hspace{1cm} \text{$\forall n, k$}$$

Hence, 
$$
1-G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n)+\log(G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n))\leq -\frac{1}{2n^2} \hspace{1cm} \text{$\forall n, k$}
$$
$$
\Downarrow
$$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (1-G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n)+\log(G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n)))\leq -\frac{1}{n} \hspace{1cm} \text{$\forall n$}
$$
How do I conclude that the limit is zero?

**CASE 2**: $t$ such that $t+\bar{u}\geq 0$. This is much more complicated because we may have $t+u_k\geq 0$ for some $k$ and $t+u_k\leq 0$ for some other. I divide into two subcases.

**SUBCASE 2.1**: $\max_{k} \{t+u_k\}\leq 0$. In this case
$$
0<G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n)\leq G(b_n)=1-\frac{1}{n}\leq G(a_n*(t+\bar{u})+b_n) \hspace{1cm} \text{$\forall n, k$}
$$
and we go back to case 1.

**SUBCASE 2.2**: $\max_{k} \{t+u_k\}\geq 0$. In this case
$$
1-\frac{1}{n}=G(b_n)\leq G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n)\leq G(a_n*(t+\bar{u})+b_n) \hspace{1cm} \text{$\forall n$, for at least one $k$}
$$
$$
0<G(a_n*(t+u_k)+b_n)\leq G(b_n)=1-\frac{1}{n}\leq G(a_n*(t+\bar{u})+b_n) \hspace{1cm} \text{$\forall n$, for the remaining $k$}
$$
I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Please see my attempted incomplete proof, thank you

Comment: I have also corrected an horrible typo (I was using for two different objects the notation $a_n$), apologies

Comment: The statement on $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ is wrong. Taking, say, $g(s)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\pi(1+s^2)}$, you get $a_n=\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{n}\csc^2\frac{\pi}{n}\to\infty$ when $n\to\infty$. This "hit or miss" doesn't break the rest - I'm still looking at it.

Comment: Thanks. Notice that the integral of $g$ should give me a continuous and strictly monotone increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ function $G$. Indeed, we can think of $G$ as a cumulative distribution function and $g$ as the probability density function.

Comment: This example of $g$ still "breaks" the statement if $t+\bar{u}<-\pi$ (in this case $a_n(t+\bar{u})+b_n\to-\infty$ when $n\to\infty$). As for the rest, I fear that simply bounding $u_k$ is not enough (for a definite resolution).

Comment: There is something ensuring that $G(a_n(t+u_k)+b_n)=G(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n(t+u_k)+b_n) =G(\infty)=1 $ $\forall t,u_k$. Let me think more where I have left that assumption.

Comment: I have added an assumption (this exercise comes from Extreme Value Theory and that assumptions ensures that $G$ is in the domain of attraction of a Gumbel).

Comment: Could you please give an example of $G$ (or maybe $g$) satisfying these new conditions?

Comment: For example, $G$ is the cdf of a standard normal distribution and $g$ is the pdf of a standard normal distribution.

Comment: OK, got it - under these conditions everything is easy; see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can even claim that, for any $v\in\mathbb{R}$, $c_n(t)+\bar{c}_n(t) \to 0$ with $n\to\infty$ uniformly for $t \geqslant v$.

For $x\in(0,1)$, $L(x)=1-x+\log x$ is monotonically increasing, so $t+u_k \geqslant v$ implies
$$ 0 \geqslant c_n(t)+\bar{c}_n(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}L(G(a_n(t+u_k)+b_n)) \geqslant 2nL(G(a_n v+b_n)).$$
But the "ADDED" condition implies $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n(1-G(a_n v+b_n))=e^{-v}$ (take $s=b_n$), so
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}nL(G(a_n v+b_n))=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(1-G(a_n v+b_n))\frac{L(G(a_n v+b_n))}{1-G(a_n v+b_n)}$$
exists and is equal to $0$ because $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{L(x)}{1-x}=0$.

Comment: @methamorphy if you have time, look at my other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751845/local-uniform-convergence-of-the-terms-of-a-sum-is-sufficient-for-convergence-of